# Toggle switch not change it state(ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have toggle  switch in my View

Here is code

```css
.switch {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 34px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    left: 4px;
    bottom: 4px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
    background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
    transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
    border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
  <div id="switcher" class="doctors-appointment">
        <div class="Row">
            <div class="Column">
                <b>Doctor's appointment</b>
            </div>
            <div class="Column">
                <label class="switch">
                    <input type="checkbox">
                    <span class="slider round"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="Column">
                <b>For internal purposes</b>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In this snippet all okay. But when I run it on my machine toggle switch not change it state.In console I have no errors.

I tried to create new css file for toggle and include it in View. But this not helps.

In what it may be problem?

Thank's for help.

Comment: What does this have to do with asp.net?

Comment: Project is ASP.NET @Marco

Comment: And what do you mean it does not change state? Does the checkbox not work or do CSS styles not get applied?

Comment: it always grey and don't changing state @Marco

Comment: Your code does work here on Stackoverflow, which means you are not showing us everything.

Comment: @SukhomlinEugene did you ever solve your issue with the toggle switch when you submit your form does it submit the correct value based on the on or off state?